# Does Sona's passive work on inhibitors?

Tags: league-of-legends

When Power Chord is active and I hit an unit (champion, turret, etc), I will deal extra damage and apply an effect based in my active aura (if it is a minion, neutral monster or champion).

> **Power Chord (Passive)** (Innate): After casting 3 spells, Sona's next attack deals extra 8 + (10 × level) magic damage. This enhanced attack has an additional effect depending on which spell was cast last.

Does this also work on inhibitors?

Comment: May i know why the downvote ? so i can fix ? Thank you in advance =)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it is probably because this question doesn't have an answer.

It is either because it is a bug, or because they purposely programmed it not to.  Without the designer/implementer commenting this is unknowable.

Comment: I do know that there's a "bug" in how Sona's Power Chord works on Inhibitors in that, if you have 3 stacks, you don't consume the Power Chord buff on your next auto-attack if you're attacking an inhibitor.  I've used it a few times. :)

Comment: This question is off topic/not constructive: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-thes

Comment: @Brandon - that is what he is talking about.  You attack and it looks like it PC's over and over, but doesn't do extra damage or consume the buff.

Comment: @RentheUnclean Ah.  I was never aware that it wasn't doing the extra damage.  We're usually winning by that point, so I've never paid it much attention. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed by Riot to be a bug, and it will be fixed in an upcoming patch.

[Source:](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=28702634#post28702634)

> just tested a fix for this—going to try to get it into the next
>   release. looks like powerchord was set up to deal damage to inhibitors
>   and the nexus (which is why it was consumed) but a bug was preventing
>   it from being applied. we're just going to fix the bug, so sona will
>   be able to powerchord inhibitors (and the nexus) when that goes out.
>
> you can't diminuendo or slow structures though, so be mindful of that
>   if you're going to use your passive for extra damage.

Comment: I would hope you can't slow structures. Then I'd never be able to sleep for fear of waking to that pinging sound...

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not.

Sona's passive deals damage to turrets, champions, minions, and creeps.
Sona's passive does not deal damage to (or get consumed by attacking) inhibitors or the nexus.

From leagueoflegends.wikia.com:

> Power Chord will not trigger if attacking an enemy inhibitor or nexus, but the animation and sound will still play (over and over again, because the Power Chord is never actually spent).

[Abilities that damage turrets](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tower)

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. I was really annoyed about that sound.